# Частица "то" с глаголом

Tags: синтаксис

"ЧЕРЕЗ ДЕФИС пишутся частицы:

```
-ТО, -ЛИБО, -НИБУДЬ, КОЕ- (КОЙ-) в составе неопределенных местоимений и наречий, например: ЧТО-ТО, КТО-ЛИБО, ЧЕЙ-НИБУДЬ, КОЕ-КАКОЙ, ОТКУДА-ТО, КАК-НИБУДЬ, КОЕ-ГДЕ."
```

А если с глаголом? Например - "Как Вас взяли_то?" Ставится здесь дефис или нет?

Answer (score 10):

Правильно: "как вас взяли-то", дефис пишется.

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

Названные частицы -ТО, -ЛИБО, -НИБУДЬ, КОЕ- являются словообразовательными, входит в состав неопределённых местоимений и наречий и пишутся через дефис.

Частица ТО дополнительно употребляется после различных частей речи (для подчёркивания и выделения в предложении слова, к которому относится): Слушать-то слушал, да ничего не понял. Однако мост-то наш каков. Неужто-таки и грешные-то молитвы мои не доходили. Как-то милые в дальнем краю? Я-то понимаю. Ночь-то какая тёплая! Где-то он сейчас? Что дальше-то делать будешь?

Через дефис пишутся также частицы разговорного характера: -ка, -де, -с, -таки, тка-, тко-: подай-ка, всё-таки, да-с, приеду-де, ну-тка, ну-тко .  Дождался-таки свободы. Успел-таки на поезд.  Принес-таки двойку!

Раздельное написание используется как исключение: кое с кем (предлог), всё ж таки (частица), он таки пришел, самолет таки опоздал, приятная таки внешность (инверсия). Она таки сдержала слово.  Таки навязался в попутчики.