# Как правильно пишется: "было то" или "было-то"?

Tags: орфография, частица, раздельно-дефис

В таком контексте -а что это было-то? А что это было то?

Answer (score 1):

Зависит от контекста. Если **то** выступает в роли частицы, то с глаголом пишется через дефис: ***Было-то всего два часа на всё про всё.*** (Также см. [здесь](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/33332/%D0%A7%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0-%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%81-%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BC))

Если же **то** выступает в роли местоимения, то пишется безо всякого дефиса: ***Было то, было это.***

Comment: В данном случае имеем предложение "А что это было-то?", здесь *-то* — частица.

Answer (score 0):

*-то*, *-либо*, *-нибудь* и *кое-* пишем через дефис.

> Через дефис пишутся частицы: -ТО, -ЛИБО, -НИБУДЬ, КОЕ- (КОЙ-) в составе неопределенных местоимений и наречий, например: ЧТО-ТО, КТО-ЛИБО, ЧЕЙ-НИБУДЬ, КОЕ-КАКОЙ, ОТКУДА-ТО, КАК-НИБУДЬ,
>   КОЕ-ГДЕ.

С [Грамоты.ру](http://gramota.ru/class/coach/tbgramota/45_122)

У вас не совсем тот случай, но и здесь *-то* будет писаться через дефис: *Что это было-то?*

Comment: Лучше сослаться на параграф 143 пункт 1 ПАС: http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=75#pp75